# Interface extending classes with same method name and return type should show error message

Tags: typescript

```
class A {
  common(): string {
    return "1"
  }
}

class B {
  common(): number {
    return 1;
  }
}

interface C extends A, B { }
```

If `interface C extends A, B`  we get the following ts error:

> Interface 'C' cannot simultaneously extend types 'A' and 'B'. 
> Named property 'common' of types 'A' and 'B' are not identical.

I need Typescript to treat in as an error even if property 'common' of types 'A' and 'B' **are** identical.
Meaning that Typescript will show an error message as well by changing property 'common' of type 'B' to this:

```
class B {
  common(): string {
    return "1";
  }
}
```

Desired error message example:

> Interface 'C' cannot simultaneously extend types 'A' and 'B'. 
> Types 'A' and 'B' both contain named property 'common'.

Comment: Why? It's valid if both properties have the same type and name.

Comment: I don't want it to be valid because in my actual code I use mixins to merge the corresponding A,B classes with a C Class. So a method of class A should never have the same name with a method of class B because a form of property shadowing will occur during merging. Meaning the new merged C class will either have 'common method' of class A or class B. The other will be overwritten. I can avoid it with runtime check but I was hoping my colleagues will get imediatelly notified for this by typescript checking.

Comment: Would something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wXjJVm) work for you? The error message is slightly confusing, but if you add documentation comments, they should show in the tooltips, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wORb7W).

Comment: Well, I tested it on my implementation and it works. Excluding a more appropriate error message it does exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think a better error message is possible at all.